# Is that a poisson distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution

I have the following example.

The car produced on some plant contains a lot of details. We are interested in quality of some certain detail type. Particularly we know, that the car contains N details of this type. Each detail can have a defect with 0.05% probability.

The defective car is defined as a car containing at least one defective detail.

The question is - what is the distribution of defective cars? Is that Poisson distribution? If yes, what are the parameters?

P.S.: This is not a question from contest, homework, course or whatever. This comes from my job.

Comment: This sounds more like a binomial distribution than a poisson.

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ is the probability of a detail being faulty, then the probability that the car is *not* defective is

$$p(D = 0) = (1 - p)^N.$$

$D$ is Bernoulli distributed. There is one assumption here and that is that the quality of the details is independent of each other. I.e., if you find one faulty detail on a car, it should not increase the probability of another detail being faulty.

The probability that a car is defective is $q = 1 - (1 - p)^N$. If you were looking at $M$ cars, the number of defective cars would be binomially distributed with parameters $(M, q)$, not Poisson. If you were looking at the time it takes until the first car is defective, you would get a geometric distribution.

Comment: Since the question gives a very small value for $p$ and describes $N$ as "a lot," don't you think the Poisson distribution would be an excellent approximation?

Comment: A Poisson distribution with $\lambda = Np$ would indeed be an excellent approximation to the number of faulty details, so one could do $q \approx 1 - e^{-Np}$. But note that the askers question was about the distribution of defective _cars_, although perhaps not the indented question.

Comment: Good point! (+1)